# Консервативность славянских языков

Tags: лингвистика

Вот интересно, какой из славянских языков самый консервативный? Какой из них ближе всего к старославянскому и где больше всего именно славянских, а не заимствованных, слов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обсуждалось тут нечто похожее... Попробую позже найти.

А вообще ситуация такая. Старославянский как таковой, на позднем особенно этапе, не был единым. Каждый диалект (или говор) положил начало своей группе более поздних и современных языков, поэтому говорить о близости к старославянскому вообще не приходится. Надо указать эталон для сравнения. За отсутствием такого эталона, единственно возможный вариант - церковнославянский (современного извода), ближе всего к нему, естественно, болгарский, поскольку он такой же потомок протоболгарского, как и современный ЦСЯ.

По ходу разговора замечу, что близость языков определяется не только - и даже не столько - словарным запасом вообще, сколько грамматикой и несколькими сотнями или тысячами наиболее употребительных слов.  Каждый язык в чем-то близок к своему предку, в чем-то отошел от него больше остальных. В польском, например, сохранились носовые гласные, в македонском, если не ошибаюсь, остатки двойственного числа, в том же болгарском - развитая система глагольных времен...

Что же касается непосредственно словарного запаса, то это скорее всего какой-то из малых угнетенных или исчезающих языков, не имевших возможности ни самостоятельно развиваться, ни обогощаться за счет заимствований... Полабский, например.

Comment: >в македонском, если не ошибаюсь, остатки двойственного числа

У словенцев и лужичан сохранилось двойственное число. 

Насчёт македонцев не могу точно сказать, но кажется у них не сохранилось.

Comment: Может быть автор просто спутал македонский со словенским...

Answer (score 2):

Старославянский — это древнеболгарский местности возле Салоник.
Болгарский во многом сохранил лексический запас древнего языка, но совершенно изменился в смысле грамматики (существительные и артикли), и в этом плане сейчас не похож ни на какой иной славянский язык.

Полагаю, что наиболее близким по лексике и грамматике можно считать сербскохорватский язык, особенно по склонению существительных и глагольным временам. Но в сербскоховатском нет носовых гласных, сместилось назад ударение в слове и появились т.н. балканские черты: наряду с выражением типа *собираюсь пойти* имеется *собираюсь да пойду*, не содержащее инфинитива (как в греческом и нынешнем болгарском).
Так что четкого ответа на вопрос не существует, все-таки прошло 1200 лет.